# What if I want to increase bounty by somebody else?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I found an exciting question that somebody gave bounty of 50, and I would like to increase it. Seems there is no way to do it. Why?

Also, I never tried this so I don't know: can I increase my own bounty before it expires, and delay its expiration in this way?